# Matplotlib polar histogram has shifted bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am using Matplotlib to create a polar histogram. The correct data for the histogram, in radians is below:

[image: Histogram Plot]

The alignment is [0,0.78) radians (aka 0 to 45 degrees) [0.78,...) (45 to 90 degrees) etc.

However, when plotting it with the polar plot, the bin is now centred on 0 rather than starting at 0. Yet the histogram count is the same.

[image: Radial Plot]

If it was actually (-22.5 degrees, 22.5 degrees), then the histogram distribution would be different. Therefore it seems like the polar plot axis label is incorrect - that is, the 0 degrees label should actually be 22.5 degrees (or alternatively the 0 degrees label should be shifted 22.5 degrees clockwise).

Is there any way anyone knows how to achieve this?

Relevant Code:
Histogram

```
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, bins_number + 1)
n, _, _ = plt.hist(angles, bins) # Create histogram
plt.show()
```

*Note, angles is a list of angles in radians*

Polar

```
plt.clf()
width = 2 * np.pi / bins_number
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n, width=width, bottom=0.0)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open('circ2.csv', 'r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        angles=[] # Initialise empty list
        next(reader) # Skip header line
        for row in reader:
                angle = float(row[1]) # Angle is in the second column of the row
                angles.append(angle)

bins_number = 8  # the [-180, 180) interval will be subdivided into this
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, bins_number + 1)

n, _, _ = plt.hist(angles, bins) # Create histogram


plt.clf()
width = 2 * np.pi / bins_number
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='polar')
bars = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n, width=width, bottom=0.0)
for bar in bars:
    bar.set_alpha(0.5)
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Share the complete minimal working code to reproduce your figures. Currently it's unknown what `bins_number` is and what `angles` is. Provide all the variables

Comment: Added full code

Comment: Without looking deeply into this, I would guess you can set `align="left"` for the bar plot.

Comment: Yep, looks like you are right. Exact code to fix this was: `align='edge'` for the bar plot. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding `align='edge'` in the bar plot. That is:

```
bars = ax.bar(bins[:bins_number], n, width=width, bottom=0.0, align='edge')
```

Thanks to [ImportanceOfBeingErnest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest)